# How to combine get method parameter and div id name without javascript?

Tags: php, html

This is simplified code of index.php :

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="course">
<button>Find</button>
</form>
```

Suppose, in the text field "**ADAM**" is put and after pressing **Find** button url becomes

```
myweburl/index.php?course=ADAM
```

But I want to make it

```
myweburl/index.php?course=ADAM#courseid
```

NB: Here **courseid** is a div id name inside index.php. By this way, I will be able to scroll down the result area.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it in a more legitimate way

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="course">
<input type="hidden" name="courseid" value="<?php echo $courseId;?>">
<button>Find</button>
</form>
```

Then you get a url like this

```
myweburl/index.php?course=ADAM&courseid=1234
```

Now you dont have to do any text manipulation in the script that processes the data you just use

```
$_GET['course']
$_GET['courseid']
```

Comment: `I will be able to scroll down the result area.` - I believe that the "issue" would be integrate the `$_GET['courseid']` parameter in his `JS`/`html id`/`a name` and that's why the OP ask regarding the `hashtag` option.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Ahh I did not get that the first time of reading the question. So you think he wants to scroll to an internal page anchor. Of course.

Comment: @OfirBaruch No I think you are right, he will probably move his tick once he has had a play with it

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the hashtag to the action attribute.
The browser would know to move it to the end of the url string (after the GET parameters).

```
<form action="index.php#courseID" method="get">
<input type="text" name="course">
<button>Find</button>
</form>
```

Would result:

index.php?course=xxxx#bla

Tested on Chrome, if someone find other results please update.

Comment: It related to your issue with the hashtag, however if possible I'll recommend you following @RiggsFolly's answer (If you have no restrictions to change your code a bit)